# Super users, do any of you recognize this web browser?

Tags: browser

Had this bug report from a client, and the screen shot provided shows a web browser I have never seen before. Can anyone identify it? In fact I'm not even entirely sure of the OS either.

[image: Strange Unknown Browser]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Window of the World](http://www.theworld.cn/tw/)

Comment: What rendering engine is it using? From what I can find it claims to use IE rendering.. Why would my pages be running fine in IE but not this then? Sigh.

Comment: @Shogun: It sounds like it is using its own browser style sheet, or enables a user stylesheet by default. Does your CSS 'reset' all defaults? If it does not, try doing that.

Comment: What the?! Is this a popular web browser in Asia?

Comment: dunno, it's Japanese though I know that much

Comment: No, it's Chinese. The third character is almost never used in Japanese.

Comment: I stand corrected :)